Proton Network ошибка создания комнаты
Я создаю комнату используя Proton Network, но появляется ошибка:

CreateRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking)but not ready for operations (State: PeerCreated). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.

Вот функция, в которой появляется эта ошибка:
PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(string.Format("[PUBLIC MATCH] {0}", PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber + Random.Range(0, 999)), new RoomOptions()
    {
        MaxPlayers = (byte)maxPlayers,
            IsVisible = false,
            IsOpen = false,
        CustomRoomProperties = roomOption,
        CleanupCacheOnLeave = true,
        CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = properties

    }, null);
    StartCoroutine (FadeIn ());

Помогите пожалуйста, почему такая ошибка? Как ее исправить?

Ошибка говорит о том, что код создания комнаты надо размещать в одном из указанных обработчиков.

Ещё может быть проблема в том, что вы уже присоединились к комнате. Чтобы сменить комнату, перед этим нужно выйти из нее с помощью PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom() и в методе OnConnectedToMaster вызвать PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom())
